# How get cookie from http headers

Tags: python, cookies, soap, suds

```
from suds import WebFault
from suds.client import Client
from cookielib import Cookie

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = Client(url)
loginResult = client.service.Login(username, password)
print "=========================================="
print client.options.transport.cookiejar
```

```
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL:http://127.0.0.1:34014
HEADERS: {'SOAPAction': u'""', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Soapaction': u'""'}

DEBUG:suds.transport.http:received:

CODE: 200

HEADERS: {
  'set-cookie': 'srv=869aa1577003769cbff7962d77641c4ae9134ac4;Domain=...;Path=/;Version=1;Max-Age=3600',
  'content-length': '440',
  'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
  'connection': 'close',
  'server': 'soap/1.9'
}

==========================================

    <cookielib.CookieJar[]>

==========================================
None
```

Comment: Why do you think there should be any cookies?

Comment: 'set-cookie': 'srv=869aa1577003769cbff7962d77641c4ae9134ac4 - is not cookie? How get value of srv ?

Answer (score 0):

If client.options.transport.cookiejar it means that cookielib can't create cookies from the response. You should look to cookie validation in the cookielib